# mxgraph copy & paste at cursor position

Tags: mxgraph

Need help with code paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> Cells at the mouse cursor position on the graph.

I studied the code example: https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/clipboard.html

but do not understand how to change code to paste the copied Cells in the place where the position `(x,y)` of the mouse cursor on the graph (not at the offset point relative to the copied cells)